# CakePHP 3: Where do it put general DB code?

Tags: php, model, cakephp-3.0

I try to figure out where to put my code to rebuild the entire database. As far as I understood it it needs to go somewhere inside the `Model` directory as it is plainly for accessing the database. It is not a `Behaviour` because it is not reusable. It is not an `Entity` as it does not give access to data inside of a table. And it is not a `Table` as it resets the entire database.

So, where do I put a class to reset my DB (or update it to the current version)? Is there an overview where to put which code and how to access it from there?

Thanks for any help!

Regards,
Alex

Edit: I tink my problem is understanding the MVC patterns. Could you give me your best practices of where to put you general code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Rebuilding the entire database" sounds pretty much like what the Migrations plugin does: https://github.com/cakephp/migrations

To directly answer your question, you can create your own classes anywhere inside the folder structure. For example you could have a file `src/Database/Rebuilder.php` that you can invoke from anywhere in the code where you need it:

```
$rebuilder = new \App\Database\Rebuilder(ConnectionManager::get('default'));
```